# How does implode() work with array of variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables, implode

I have an array of variables:

```
$values = array($a,$b,$c);
```

i want to pass this array through this function:

```
function db_insert($table, $attributes, $values)//insert into the database
{
    // $values and takes an array of variables. $attributes is a string  "att1, att2,...."
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ' '".$table."' ( '".$attributes."' ) VALUES ( '".implode("','", $values)."' )");    
    return $result;
}
```

I pass it like this but it doesn't work:

```
db_insert("table","a,b,c",$values);
```

There is no errors but the record is not stored into the database. What is the problem?

Comment: If you echo `"INSERT INTO ' '".$table."' ( '".$attributes."' ) VALUES ( '".implode("','", $values)."' )"` and execute it manually on the db does it work?

Comment: Yes i tried that. It works

Comment: Have you tried this as well?

`if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}`

Comment: `"INSERT INTO ' '".$table."'` Besides a spurious `'` anyway; don't wrap a table name in `'`.... if you wrap it, wrap it in backticks (`\``).... likewise for column names (attributes)

Comment: @hzjw - if you had echoed the sql query, and tried to execute it manually on the database, it would have errored

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table ($attributes) VALUES ('".implode("','", $values)."')");
```

As a side note you should switch to using `mysqli_` functions or PDO instead of `mysql_`, [see why here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). You should also read a bit on placeholders and how to use them in your queries.